# Why does sampling a percentage of a specific span name ends up affecting all spans?

Tags: open-telemetry

I'm setting up telemetry for a web app where there I want to only send 1% of the spans for a specific (very frequent) span name. I did this by implementing a `Sampler` which returns a `RECORD` decision for all spans except the one with name `'some.specific.span'` which is `RECORD_AND_SAMPLED` in 1% of cases and `NOT_RECORD`ed in 99% of cases:

```js
class MySampler implements Sampler {
  sampleProb = 0.01; // sample with 1% probability

  shouldSample(_context: Context, _traceId: string, spanName: string): SamplingResult {
    if (spanName === 'some.specific.span') {
      const decision =
        Math.random() < this.sampleProb ? SamplingDecision.RECORD_AND_SAMPLED : SamplingDecision.NOT_RECORD;
      return { decision, attributes: { SampleRate: 1 / this.sampleProb } };
    }

    return { decision: SamplingDecision.RECORD };
  }

  toString(): string {
    return 'MySampler';
  }
}

export function setupTelemetry() {
  const provider = new BasicTracerProvider({sampler: new MySampler()});
  provider.addSpanProcessor(new BatchSpanProcessor(new OTLPTraceExporter()));
  provider.register();
}
```

However, in practice, it seems to be discarding 99% of *all* traces. What on earth is going on here? Did I misunderstand something fundamental about how samplers work?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to return `RECORD_AND_SAMPLED` for samples I want to be included:

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/blob/e133f3f5c/packages/opentelemetry-sdk-trace-base/src/Tracer.ts#LL116-L118